# How Can Set FullWidth Image in PagerView in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to Set FullWidth Image in this ImagePagerView. That every Image will be fullwidth and height for viewing in every page.Any Help Please. The Java code is given below. Any Help Please.

```
package com.exampe.imagepager;

public class FragmentImageView extends Fragment {
package com.exampe.imagepager;

public class FragmentImageView extends Fragment {

private Integer itemData;
private Bitmap myBitmap;
public ProgressDialog pd;
private ImageView ivImage;

public static FragmentImageView newInstance() {
    FragmentImageView f = new FragmentImageView();
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public View onCreateView

(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageview, container, false);

    ivImage = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.ivImageView);

    setImageInViewPager();

    return root;
}

public void setImageList(Integer integer) {
    this.itemData = integer;
}

public void setImageInViewPager() {

    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), itemData,
                options);
        if (options.outWidth > 3000 || options.outHeight > 2000) {
            options.inSampleSize = 4;
        } else if (options.outWidth > 2000 || options.outHeight > 1500) {
            options.inSampleSize = 3;
        } else if (options.outWidth > 1000 || options.outHeight > 1000) {
            options.inSampleSize = 2;
        }
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), itemData,options);

if (myBitmap != null) {
            try {
                if (ivImage != null) {
                    ivImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                }
            } 

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.gc();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (myBitmap != null) {
        myBitmap.recycle();
        myBitmap = null;
    }


 }
}
```

Xml Code Is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
 >

 <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/ivImageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example use:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```